# updating the ContentView of android dialog without close when it is showing

Tags: android, view, dialog, android-alertdialog

I am trying to show my custom view in a **dialog** bu using **alertDialog.Builder** with below code snippet.

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertViewBuilder = null;
AlertDialog alertViewDialog = null;
public void showPopupView(View popupView) {

if (alertViewBuilder == null) {
    alertViewBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctContext);
}
    alertViewBuilder.setView(popupView);

if (alertViewDialog == null)
    alertViewDialog = alertViewBuilder.create();

if (!alertViewDialog.isShowing())
    alertViewDialog.show();
}
```

if user perform any action on the components of that custom view, i wants to change/update the content of the **dialog**. so when user touches/clicks on any component of the custom view i am updating the **popupView** and passing the updated **popupView** to **showPopupView(View popupView)** again. but view is not getting updated on the **dialog**.

My requirement is similar the following example.

1. showing login page with **username**, **password** Text-input Fields and "**OK**" button on a dialog.
2. if user entered wrong username/password and press "**OK**" button the same **Dialog** should be updated with a view which will have an Error message textview instead of **username** & **password** Text-input Fields and "**OK**" button should be replaced with **"Try Again"** Button on the same Dialog.
3. when user press "Try Again" button previous login page should be displayed on the same Dialog.

I mean flow should some thing similar to the changing view's on same activity.
I think i've provided the sufficient information about my problem. 
Please suggest me some solution to my problem.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I am able to manage and find the solution for this issue. just removed **AlertDialog.Builder** and changed **AlertDialog** to **Dialog** and calling addContentView(view) in **Dialog** instead of calling setView(view) on **AlertDialog.Builder**. and adding and removing chaildviews on the contentview on the **Dialog**. find the below code snippet.

```
private android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams alertLayoutParams = null;
private Dialog alertViewDialog = null;
private LinearLayout cvPopupView;

public void showPopupView(View popupView) {
    if (cvPopupView == null)
        cvPopupView = new LinearLayout(ctContext);
    else
        cvPopupView.removeAllViews();

    cvPopupView.addView(popupView);

    if (alertViewDialog == null) {
        alertViewDialog = new Dialog(ctContext);
        alertViewDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    }

    if (alertLayoutParams == null) {
        alertLayoutParams = new android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    }

    if (!alertViewDialog.isShowing()) {
        alertViewDialog.addContentView(cvPopupView, alertLayoutParams);
        alertViewDialog.show();
    }
}
```

this may help, if any one else facing same kind of problem.

Comment: Can you please explain what does "addContentView" do? APIs say it just adds it, but that it can't be removed, and I also can't get those views. What if I want, for example, switch from full screen progress bar to a normal alertDialog style and vice versa?